# Executing multiple commands with setlock

Tags: linux, bash, locking

In a bash script I would like to execute multiple commands while keeping a file locked with setlock. Setlock however only supports the following usage:

setlock [-NnXx] [lock file] [command]

Is there a way to wrap multiple commands together besides using a separated script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sh` as a command, enabling you to use `&&`, `;` or `||` as usual to chain multiple commands as desired inside single quotes.

For example to run `command1` followed by `command2` (if the first exits without errors):

```
setlock lockfile sh -c 'command1 && command2'
```